# What are the blue dots next to App names in iOS and macOS?

Tags: macos, ios, applications, ui

They disappear once you open the apps and then return to the home screen, but I can't tell what they indicate.

Are they apps that haven't been opened since an app update? Or that it thinks have never been opened (not accurate in my case, but that could be a function of a "restore" confusing the phone).

[image]
[image]

Answer (score 24, accepted):

The blue dot is the *replacement* to the banner that iOS 6 had for a new app.

[image: New App Banner]

There are two conditions for a banner being shown:

- an app has been downloaded from the App Store but has not been opened yet

  (a restore from iTunes/iCloud will also cause an app to be classed as 'New')
- an app has been updated but has not been opened since it has been updated

  (this counts for manually updated apps or apps that have been automatically updated by iOS 7's new background app updater).

As soon as the app is opened, the dot is removed.

Answer (score -1):

that means they are new. as in "unopened since last update"

Comment: Thanks - to clarify, is that new, as in, "Never opened", "not opened since last update", or something else?

Answer (score -1):

They indicate that the app was recently updated and has not yet been launched since the update.

The pale blue dot will appear either if iOS 7 updated the app with Automatic Updates or if the user updated it manually.

In iOS 6, when you installed a new app, its icon would display a small "new" banner across one corner. In iOS 7, new apps are represented by a blue dot.
That dot also appears when you update an existing app (or the OS updates it for you in the background). In both cases, the dot disappears after you launch that app for the first time.

http://reviews.cnet.com/8301-19512_7-57603848-233/five-quick-ios-7-mysteries-solved/