# What does the blue point before app name in lauchpad mean?

Tags: macos, icon, launchpad

[image]

As the arrows point, the little blue points before Evernote and MS OneNote.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

The recommendation system of stackexchange really helps, I got [this](https://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/101530/what-are-the-blue-dots-next-to-app-names-in-ios-7) when I asked the question.

It turns out the little blue point shows I haven't opened the app since the app's last update.

Comment: Same on iDevices too.